# No default RealmConfiguration was found. Call setDefaultConfiguration()

Tags: java, android, realm

I am trying to learn how to use Realm by creating simple testing app, but I am getting this error always. I am using Realm 1.0.0.
The error in the logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: No default RealmConfiguration was found. 
Call     setDefaultConfiguration()
```

This is the code in the Mainactivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText name;
EditText age;
TextView result;
Realm myRealm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    result= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    myRealm= Realm.getDefaultInstance();

}
public void store(){
myRealm.beginTransaction();
    User user=myRealm.createObject(User.class);
    user.setName(name.getText().toString());
    user.setAge(Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()));
    myRealm.commitTransaction();
}

public void load(View view) {
    RealmResults<User>results=myRealm.where(User.class).findAll();
    StringBuffer stingBuffer=new StringBuffer();
    for(User user:results){
        stingBuffer.append(user.getName()+" - "+user.getAge()+"\n");
    }
    result.setText(stingBuffer.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add
RealmCOnfiguration in you MyApplication file

// Setup Realm in your Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was the solution.

Comment: In your Manifest file inside application tag use android:name tag with the class name<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
       >